# Error with extra info on $scope during navigation

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

maybe somebody catches this problem.
I have two pages "List of course" and "Course search result". When I do to transition between those pages (with help navigation) appears extra information on both page.  I used $scope.data on the both page (but I keep there different info) I have the feeling that some of the information still comes from the page with which I moved, thereby changing the $scope.data on both pages. Because when I changed $scope.data on $scope.dataResult for "Course search result" page, my problem was fixed.
Sorry, but I couldn't show code, because this is real project with real data :(

Comment: You can show your code if you don't mind taking to time to generalize the name and trivialize the data.

Comment: No code, no party... :-)

Comment: Sounds like you have nested controllers, so one `$scope` is a parent to another `$scope`. If you want the scopes to be separate you can't put one controller inside another.